# Is it true that each prime number $p_i$ could be represented $p_i=p_j+p_k \pm 1, \ i \neq j \neq k, \ p_i>5$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is it true that each prime number greater then 3 could be written as sum of two not sequent primes plus-minus 1.

$p_i=p_j+p_k \pm 1, \ i \neq j \neq k, \ p_i>5$

It's appears to be Goldbach conjecture or ? :)

Comment: Does "sequent primes" mean "consecutive primes" ?

Comment: Is $p_j=p_k$ allowed ?

Comment: Seems that every even $n\ge 14$ allows a representation $n=p+q$ with primes $p<q$, such that $p$ and $q$ are not consecutive primes. This would immediately prove the claim for every prime $p\ge 13$. Hence a slightly stronger version of Goldbach's conjecture would be enough. This stronger version holds for the even $n$ with $14\le n\le 5\cdot 10^5$.

Comment: You mean "each prime number greater than 5",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It follows from the Goldbach conjecture: Let p ≥ 7 be a prime. Then according to the Goldbach conjecture, both p-1 and p+1 are the sum of two primes. One of them could be equal to twice an odd prime, but then the other is twice an even number, and therefore not twice an odd prime, but the sum of two different primes. p = 5 fails because neither 4 nor 6 are the sum of different primes, so does p = 3 and p = 2. Of course the Goldbach conjecture is unproven.